# Build a matrix norm on 2x2 matrices such that for given $A$ we have that $||A^n||$ converges

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

> $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
>         -0.5 &  0\\ 
>           0  & 1.3
>         \end{pmatrix} $$
>
> Build a matrix norm on $2 \times 2$ matrices such that for the given $A$ we have that $\|A^n\|$ converges **or** prove that such norm doesn't exist.

Comment: All matrix norms are equivalent, meaning that for any two matrix norms $\|\cdot \|_{\alpha}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\beta}$ we have some positive real numbers $r$ and $s$ such that $r\|A\|_{\alpha}\leq \|A\|_{\beta}\leq s\|A\|_{\alpha}$.  Now, try using your favorite matrix norm in place of $\|\cdot\|_{\alpha}$ such that it is easy to show $\|A^n\|_{\alpha}$ doesn't converge.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it